# Can't install wordpress on nginx server, "welcome to nginx" showing instead of wordpress installation page

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx, nginx-config

i'm implementing this exact architecture, i'm on a Vagrant environment, each server is a vagrant box.

```
          +--------------+
                              | Load Balancer|
                              | 192.168.10.10|
                              +--------------+
                                     |
                          +----------+-----------+
                          |          |           |
           +--------------v-+  HTTP   |    MySQL  |
           |   Client 1    +--------+           |
           | 192.168.10.12 |                    |
           +--------------+-+                    |
                          |                      |
           +--------------v-+  HTTP   +-----------v-----------+
           |   Client 2    +-------->+        Client 3         |
           | 192.168.10.13 |         | 192.168.10.14 (MySQL) |
           +--------------+         +-----------------------+
```

So the load-balancer do his job perfectly.
The main problem is that on my client's boxes its shows me the "Welcome to Nginx" page instead of the wordpress installation page

This is a sample of my config on client1 :

```
total 22M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      22M May 20 04:31 latest.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4.0K Jun 16 11:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4.0K Jun 16 11:22 wordpress
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      619 Jun 16 12:13 index.nginx-debian.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4.0K Jun 16 12:13 .
```

It's seems to me that all permissions are correctly set, in fact the welcome message come from the "index.nginx-debian.html'
I tried to rename it, after that i have a 403 forbidden message.

I created a wordpress configuration file in path /etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf which contains the following config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  my.dns;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

thanks for any help you could give me

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. The request is being handled by another `server` block.